# Custom Markers For Elements In Project Browser In EA

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am working on importing and modifying requirement type elements in EA through C# add-in.

I want to add custom marker near the element in project browser similar to markers that are set when an element is locked.

[image]

I had worked on shape scripts in MDG technology yes unsure if its possible to replicate a custom marker similar to locked element.

Kindly help me if any EA API is available for the same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is: not possible.

You might send a feature request to Sparx, but that browser has the same look/functionality since I know it (2003). So - little chances.

What you "could" do it to write your own browser in a window you can open and control inside EA. But - is it worth that?

Comment: Thank you..overall I am using a form to modify the requirement elements and I wanted user to be able to understand if the requirement has been modified using the marker added to it in project browser without having to open the form everytime.

Comment: I'd use a dedicated diagram as communication base where that information can go..

Answer (score -2):

EA doesn't provide any direct API available from setting\changing the ICON.

The only option is via shape script for your **custom stereotypes**.

Comment: Thank you..is it possible to add shape script for an element through C# without creating MDG profile

Comment: Shapescripts don't change anything to the icon used in the project browser.